# Ignore error in setenv command and continue further execution of the csh script

Tags: shell, unix, error-handling, tcsh, setenv

I have a file containing set of setenv commands(Generated from another script).

***a.csh***

```
setenv XYZ "${ABC} ab"
setenv PQR "test"
```

Then I run `source a.csh` in the Linux terminal

But if the variable $ABC is not set, the source errors out with Undefined variable ABC and exits without running the next set of commands within a.csh(like `setenv PQR "test"`).

I wish to continue the execution of those set of commands after `setenv XYZ "${ABC} ab"`.

I tried adding error redirection for the setenv command, but didn't work

`setenv XYZ "${ABC} ab" 2 > /dev/null`

I found that the source command's error can be caught using

`source a.csh & echo $?`

But this will ignore the commands in the file that are following the one with the error since it exits the command on encountering the error.

This is a small example of what my csh file looks like. 
But it can contain long list of setenvs.

Checking if $ABC exists and then running setenv is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

The closest workaround I found for this was generating the setenvs as below if setenv's value contains a variable.

`[ "$?ABC" == "0" ] && echo 'Undefined $ABC' || setenv XYZ "$ABC aa"`

Could not avoid checking if the variable exists. 
But does not require if else blocks and makes it a one liner.

**Explanation:**
`$?ABC` returns 0 if the variable $ABC is not defined.

If the variable is defined `[ "$?ABC" == "0" ]` is **false** forcing the execution of || condition.
In a condition like `A && B`, B is executed only if A is true (Basic && behavior).

If variable **ABC** is undefined `[ "$?ABC" == "0" ]` is **true** and the code following `&&` is executed `echo 'Undefined $ABC'`.